# Books recommendations for my theoretical physics library

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

long story short: I got a big prize from my scholarship, which consists in a lot of money for books, and I mean a lot: almost USD$ 3000. Thus, I am going to buy lots of books, of course!

So I'm asking for book recommendations. My field is theoretical high energy physics (I work on extended SUSY and string theory, mostly), so my focus is in those topics, but not only that.

The books I'm targeting are:

1. General physics

   - Landau's vol 1, 2, 3, 5 and 9
   - Griffiths QM and Electrodynamics
   - Weinberg QM
   - "Lectures on Quantum Mechanics", Dirac
2. QFT

   - Zee's QFT in a nutshell
   - Weinberg vol 1,2,3
   - Srednicki QFT
   - Shifman Advanced topics in QFT
   - Mussardo "Statistical Field Theory"
   - Coleman's "Aspect of Symmetry"
3. String

   - the two volumes of Green, Schwarz, Witten
   - Polchinski vol 1 and 2
   - Nastase AdS/CFT book
   - Peter West "Introduction to Strings and Branes"
   - Becker^2 and Schwarz "String Theory and M-theory"
   - "Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians"
   - "A First Course in String Theory", Zwiebach
4. Group Theory

   - Ramon's "Group Theory: A Physicist's Survey "
   - "Representation Theory", Fulton
5. Susy

   - "Modern Supersymmetry Dynamics and Duality", Terning
   - "N=2 Supersymmetric Dynamics for Pedestrians", Tachikawa
   - "Supersymmetry and Supergravity", Wess and Bagger
   - "Supergravity", Freedman
6. GR

   - "General Relativity", Wald
7. Mathematical Physics

   - "The Geometry of Physics", Frankel
8. Others

   - Exactly Solved Models in Statistical Mechanics, by Baxter

Reading previous questions related to this one, I found Naber's "Topology, Geometry and Gauge Fields" and Bredon "Topology and Geometry", which seem to be good books. Witten suggested to read "some" complex analysis as part as your academic training, and I found Lang's "Complex Analysis" and the series of four volumes by Stein and Shakarchi, but I have zero experience in those topics (as far as a formal course), so I don't know if those are good choices or not. Finally, one of my academic rivals computed using harmonic superspace something I computed using the standard Minkowski superspace, and it seems interesting. He suggested to me Galperin et al "Harmonic Superspace" as a good place to learn it, what do you think about that book?

Do you have any suggestion and/or recommendation? I feel like another Stastitical Mechanics book is missing (Landau's is too hard, and next semester I may have to teach some Statistical Mechanics, as part of my future teaching duties.) Any other book that might be a good reference in the future?, some more mathematical physics (topology, geometry, group theory, etc.)?, maybe some condensed matter book for string people like me?

Comment: see also: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations

Comment: You may search for books on General Relativity by George Gamow....I don't exactly remember the name of the book...but I had seem books by this author in my school library...

Comment: What do you think about Feynman Lectures on Physics?They are a must for any Physics student...

Comment: I recommend _Geometry, Topology and Physics_ by M. Nakahara. You'll find a very good detailed explanation for all the math you need. I personally refer to it a lot.